# JSON devuelto por php y función http.onreadystatechange de XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, json

En php al cargar la página, construyo un JSON pequeño, que mando al JavaScript. Eso es lo que en un principio contiene la variable `json` del JavaScript.

Después hago un clic en pantalla, llamando a `inicio_pru.php` y éste me construye un JSON nuevo, más grande y se lo devuelve al JavaScript.

En JavaScript, la parte que recibe el evento `click` (se pincha en un nodo del árbol en pantalla, lo cual desencadena una llamada a `inicio_pru.php` para que construya un JSON más grande):

```
       onCreateLabel: function(label, node){
                label.id = node.id;            
                label.innerHTML = node.name;
                label.onclick = function(){

                  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  var url = "inicio_pru.php";
                  var params = "callFunction=arbol_completo";
                  http.open("POST", url, true);

                 //Send the proper header information along with the request
                 http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                 http.send(params);
                 http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
                    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

                      json=http.responseText;

                        st.loadJSON(json);
                        compute node positions and layout
                        st.compute();
                        //optional: make a translation of the tree
                        st.geom.translate(new $jit.Complex(-200, 0), "current");
                        //emulate a click on the root node.
                        st.onClick(node.id);
                        alert (json);


                    }
                }
                alert(json);

         };
```

En php (`inicio_pru.php`):

```
        <?php
        if($callFunction == "arbol_completo") {
                $root=recorrerArbol($children_root,$raiz); 
                $arbol1=json_encode($root);
                $arbol2=str_replace("type","\$type",$arbol1);
                $arbol3=str_replace("color","\$color",$arbol2);
                $arbol=str_replace("'","\'",$arbol3);


                echo '$arbol';
        }
        else 
        {


        $root=recorrerArbol1($children_root,$raiz);


        $arbol1=json_encode($root);
        $arbol2=str_replace("type","\$type",$arbol1);
        $arbol3=str_replace("color","\$color",$arbol2);
        $arbol=str_replace("'","\'",$arbol3);


        return '$arbol';

        }


        ?>
```

Pero al hacer `click` en un nodo del árbol, parece que la función `onclick` no hace nada, de hecho ni siquiera saca los dos alert que le he puesto.
Muchísimas gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Dónde estableces que se ejecute la función JS al hacer click? El `onCreateLabel`? Estás definiendo una función anónima (`onCreateLabel` es una etiqueta JS, no el nombre de la función) y no veo en ninguna parte que la enlaces con un evento de un elemento DOM.

Comment: Seria en el label.onclick = function(){, o sea en el objeto label, cuando dé un click sobre él

Comment: De acuerdo, `label.onclick` registra la función anónima interna, pero ¿cuándo ejecutas ese código? ¿Dónde llamas a la función anónima externa? Por lo que veo del código nunca se llama a dicha función, así que no se registra la función de evento y ya no funciona todo lo demás. Prueba añadiendo un `alert` delante de `label.id = node.id` para que veas lo que te digo.

Comment: El label.onclik se ejecuta cuando en la pantalla pulso encima del nodo , sobre la etiqueta. Ésta web lo que hace es , cuando se carga, visualiza un árbol con unos nodos con etiquetas en cada uno.Después , yo pulso en un de ellos, en el label , y es ahí donde se ejecuta el label.onclick.

Comment: Entiendo cuando se ejecuta la función asociada con el evento `onclick`. Lo que no veo es cuándo se ejecuta el codigo que define que el evento onclick; la función `function (label, node) {`. Como he dicho, pon un alert al inicio de la función y comprobarás si se ejecuta o no; si no se ejecuta no se asignara ninguna función al evento onclick...

Comment: La función oncreatelabel se ejecuta al cargar la pagina.Hay un php que llama a init , que es una función de js que es la que llama a ésta de oncretatelabel, pasándole label.innerHTML = node.name.Al cargar la página aparece en el Label el node.name, con lo que deduzco que sí se ha ejecutado la función oncreatelabel .He puesto un alert , como dices,justo debajo del function(label, node){alert ("hola")..} y efectivamente no hace nada, pero es que ésta función se ejecuta en la creación del DOM, no sé si los alert los puede sacar en ese momento.Gracias de antemano por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Una confusión muy común es liarse entre el código que genera la página (en este caso el php) y el código de la propia página.

En el código que tú tienes, no hay ninguna función javascript llamada "oncreatelabel". Hay una etiqueta JS (que no sirve para nada) y una función anónima, que es definida pero como no se guarda la referencia nunca puede ser llamada. Por eso no aparece el `alert`.

El PHP (o Java/Python/Perl/loquesea) se ejecuta únicamente en el servidor, y proporciona una página HTML (en este caso). El método PHP no puede ejecutar ningún método JS (ni de otro tipo) en el navegador, sólo genera el contenido que se envía al navegador y el navegador ya se encargara del renderizado y de la ejecución del JS.

Otra forma de verlo: el navegador sólo ve el HTML. Lo que haga el PHP (aparte de proporcional el HTML) no le afecta lo más mínimo. Cuando estés depurando JS, olvídate de cuál es el origen de la página.

Si quieres ejecutar código JS, la orden para ejecutar dicho código JS debe estar en la pagina entregada. Por ejemplo, pon la línea

```
document.onload =  function(){
  // Obtener valores de label y node
  label.id = node.id;            
  label.innerHTML = node.name;
  label.onclick = function(){
    ...
}
```

dentro de un tag de javascript pero fuera de cualquier método. Es preferible usar `document.onload` frente a `window.onload` porque con la primera te aseguras que el DOM está completamente construido.

Comment: la página que carga el HTML tiene un : <body onload="init(datos,1);">.Ese init es una función de js que hace entre otras cosas , lo siguiente:

Comment: Perdon, he dado a intro sin querer.Hace lo siguiente: onCreateLabel: function(label, node){
            label.id = node.id;            
            label.innerHTML = node.name;
   label.onclick = function(){.Te lo digo porque esto ha estado funcionando perfectamente hasta ayer.De hecho si cambio la orma de ontener datos en el php que obtiene el json, lo que hace al hacer onclikc es desplegar los hijos del nodo , y esto lo ha estado haciendo hasta ayer ...

Answer (score 0):

Estaba pasándole el json como texto y no como objeto.Al poner esto :

json=http.responseText;
**json=JSON.parse(json);**

convierte el texto json a un objeto json que puede ser ya cargado:

st.loadJSON(json);